# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'show' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting an :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'show' of null" error in a script which points out the error is somewhere in this area, see below:

```
            // Show the correct more view images and if there are moreviews displayed, display the more views title
            if (selectedmoreview !== null && selectedmoreview !== undefined && howMany > 0) {
                selectedmoreviewtitle.show();
                selectedmoreview.invoke('show');
            } else {
                if(howMany > 0){ selectedmoreviewtitle.hide(); }
            }

            spConfig.configureElement(dropdownEl);
```

Can anyone help me sort this out and have my functionality working? Some expert advice would be truly appreciated

Comment: selectedmoreviewtitle must be null --> `selectedmoreviewtitle.show();`

Comment: Hi Mario and thank you for your insight. I do not understand that - what exactly do I have to change?

Comment: What I meant is, that the error you are getting is probably caused by this line: `selectedmoreviewtitle.show();`. It means that `selectedmoreviewtitle` must be null. So you need to check where it's created, if it really is null or not. Maybe you can edit your question and add that code so we can see.

Comment: Thank you for your insight Mario. The website i experience this error in is : http://goo.gl/6ECH2 - When a specific swatch (color is clicked) it changes the image, but it should also showcase the related thumbnails, altough they are not showing. I tried to see into the javascript console and once I click on a specific swatch I get the Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'show' of null error. The file responsible for this script is located in here: http://goo.gl/BLPFY

Comment: As far as I can see (and I only looked quickly) you are trying this line of code: `selectedmoreviewtitle = $('moreviews-title');` in the colorselected.js on row 204. And there's no element with id or class named 'moreviews-title'. So that's why it gets null. Further more, you'd probably want to use class selector `'.moreviews-title'` or id selector `'#moreviews-title'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per request:

As far as I can see (and I only looked quickly) you are trying this line of code:

```
selectedmoreviewtitle = $('moreviews-title');
```

in the **colorselected.js** on row 204. And there's no element with id or class named 'moreviews-title'. So that's why it gets null.

Further more, you'd probably want to use class selector `'.moreviews-title'` or id selector `'#moreviews-title'`.

Answer (score 0):

You check `selectedmoreview`, but you try to call `selectedmoreviewtitle.show()`. Since `selectedmoreview` isn't null `selectedmoreviewtitle` probably is.